# can only enter each room once question

Tags: geometry

3x3 cube with no center square so 26 cubes, You can start where ever you like and need to visit every room(cube exactly once)

A valid operation is going any adjacent cube that is not diagonally adjacent.

How would you solve this?

Comment: you mean a 3 x 3 x 3 cube with no center square on each face? with 6 faces on the cube, each missing the center cube, that would be 8 cubes per face, 6 cubes = 48 cubes, in total.... right?

Comment: @rm-vanda wrong, that would be 8 *squares* per face, but there would be 26 *cubes* total in the 3x3x3 structure.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was thinking "rooms" === "cubes"  === "squares" - thanks for clarifying

Comment: @gnovice I didn't tag this question as a duplicate because the constraints are not the same. There you have to begin with the central cube of a face and end in the center of the 3x3 cube. Here you can begin and end wherever you like.

Comment: Damn you are right. Unfortunatly, I have already marked it as equivalent  to another question, and I can't roll it back

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> there is no solution.
>
>  See [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/22414/32339) to another puzzle. The problem is slightly different but the reasoning is the same.